# Create a hash of array: Displaying array reference

Tags: perl

Below is my code(just playing with hashes) where I want to create a hash of array(keys assigning to array). But I get the output as array reference. Why is this array reference displaying?

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 my @result = (0,0,0);
 my @operator = ('AP', 'MP', 'UP');
 my %operator_res;

 for ( $i = 0; $i <= $#operator; $i++ ) {
     if ( $i == 2 ) {
         @result = (4,5,6);
     } elsif ( $i == 1 ) {
         @result = (1,2,3);
     }
     @{$operator_res{$operator[$i]}} = @result;
 }
 foreach $keys (%operator_res) {
     print "$keys:";
     #print "@{$operator_res{$keys}}\n";
     print "$operator_res{$keys}[0], $operator_res{$keys}[1], $operator_res{$keys}[2]\n";
 }
```

Output is

```
UP:4, 5, 6
ARRAY(0x17212e70):, ,   Why is this array reference printing?
AP:0, 0, 0
ARRAY(0x17212e00):, ,
MP:1, 2, 3
ARRAY(0x17212e20):, ,
```

Comment: `print join(", ", @{ $operator_res{$keys} }), "\n";` is better than typing out all of your array elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach $keys (%operator_res)
```

should be

```
foreach $keys (keys %operator_res)
```

Comment: +1 That was a very hard to detect error. Some things you just take for granted in other people's code.

Answer (score 1):

Your `foreach` loop iterates over each element of `%operator_res`, not just over the keys. As ikagim already answered, you have to use `keys` to get only the keys of the hash.

If you have a look with `Data::Dumper` on the `%operator_res` the Output is:

```
$VAR1 = 'UP';
$VAR2 = [
          4,
          5,
          6
        ];
$VAR3 = 'AP';
$VAR4 = [
          0,
          0,
          0
        ];
$VAR5 = 'MP';
$VAR6 = [
          1,
          2,
          3
        ];
```

As you see, you will always get two iterations per element: one for the key and one for the array ref.

Answer (score 0):

A hash value in Perl must be a scalar. To simulate multidimensional hashes, use values that are *references* to hashes or arrays.

The line

```
@{$operator_res{$operator[$i]}} = @result;
```

in your question is equivalent to

```
$operator_res{ $operator[$i] } = [ @result ];
```

That is, the value associated with the key `$operator[$i]` at the time is a *reference* to a new array whose contents are the same as `@result`.

For many examples, read the [perllol documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html).

Comment: Hi Greg Bacon, if you give the reference of the array to the perl, then the %operator_res will have the same values for all the keys. I want to save the @result in the hash for the respective key.

Comment: But Greg's code doesn't take the reference of `@result`, does it? It uses the anonymous array constructor (`[ ... ]`) to create a copy of `@result` and uses the reference to that new copy.

Comment: @sach Had the code been `$operator_res{$operator[$i]} = \@result;` you would be correct. Instead, `[ @result ]` creates **a new array** whose contents are a (shallow) copy of `@result` and gives a reference to the new array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Data::Dumper to print out your data in a well formatted way:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\%operator_res);
```

Q: Why is this array reference printing?

A: Because of this line: print "$keys:";